# TSQL for xml prevent empty- and self-closing tags

Tags: xml, t-sql, tags

A while ago I asked this question:
[TSQL for xml xml-tag just once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12086720/tsql-for-xml-xml-tag-just-once)

Now I've the issue that empty- and self-closing tags shouldn't appear in the xml.

I found possible workarounds [here](http://www.sqlmusings.com/2009/04/12/sqlxml-how-to-work-with-xml-elements-or-nodes-in-sql-server/) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/denisruc/archive/2006/05/17/600250.aspx) but it doesn't work like I expect.

I also tried to write "$$" in each potential empty tag then at the end I tried to remove all the tags containing "$$" with:

```
SET @persons.modify('delete (//$$)')
```

but this approach does not work either.

**How can I remove empty- and self-closing tags with XQuery or prevent them to appear within TSQL for xml?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you write your query but generally `null` values is not included in the resulting XML so if you want to omit empty values you can use `nullif` to get a null value instead of empty.

```sql
declare @Person table
(
  Name varchar(20)
)

insert into @Person values ('Person1')
insert into @Person values ('Person2')
insert into @Person values ('')
insert into @Person values (null)

select '2012' as period,
       (
        select nullif(Person.Name, '') as 'users/person'
        from @Person as Person
        for xml path('') , type
       )
for xml path(''), root('company')
```

Result:

```xml
<company>
  <period>2012</period>
  <users>
    <person>Person1</person>
  </users>
  <users>
    <person>Person2</person>
  </users>
</company>
```